# Error message below the field

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In the below code i have put alert message to show duplicate emails. But my requirement is to put error message below the field instead of alert message.I have used lightning aura component.

Apex

```
   @AuraEnabled
   global static String getEmails(String emailstring){
        Integer len=emailstring.length();
        List<contact> con;
        if(len>0 && emailstring!=''){
            con=[select id,Email from contact where email=:emailstring]; 
        }
        system.debug('Emails checll-------'+con);
        String msg='Email already exists';
        string msg1='';
        if (con.size()>0){
            return msg;
        }  
        else return msg1;
       
    }
```

HTML

```
 <lightning:input  class="inputfields"    aura:id="email" label="Email" type="Email" name="email" value="{!v.newContact.Email}" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Please enter your Email"  pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$"  messageWhenPatternMismatch="Please Enter a valid Email Address" onchange="{!c.handleOnChangeEmail}"/>
```

JS

```
handleOnChangeEmail:function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Email---');
        var action=component.get("c.getEmails");
        action.setParams({
            "emailstring":component.get("v.newContact.Email")
        });     
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state= response.getState();
            if(state==='SUCCESS'&& response.getReturnValue()!=''){
                console.log('responseEmail---');
                alert(response.getReturnValue());
               
                component.set("v.newContact.Email",'');
            }});
        $A.enqueueAction(action);            
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show an error message within the field of a [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation) component, You can follow below steps:-

Define an aura id into your lightning:input

```
    <lightning:input aura:id="inputCmp" label="Email" 
          type="Email" name="email" required="true" .............../>
```

then you the aura id to throw error based on your condition in JS controller using **setCustomValidity() and reportValidity()**:-

```
handleOnChangeEmail:function(component, event, helper) {
    var action=component.get("c.getEmails");
    action.setParams({
        "emailstring":component.get("v.newContact.Email")
    });     
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state= response.getState();
        if(state==='SUCCESS'){
            var inputCmp = cmp.find("inputCmp");
            if (response.getReturnValue() === "Email already exists") {
                inputCmp.setCustomValidity("Email already exists");
            } else {
                inputCmp.setCustomValidity(""); // if there was a custom error before, reset it
            }
            inputCmp.reportValidity(); // Tells lightning:input to show the error right away without needing interaction
        }});
    $A.enqueueAction(action);            
},
```

- setCustomValidity - Sets a custom error message to be displayed when
  the input value is submitted.
- reportValidity - Tells lightning:input to show the error right away without needing interaction

Comment: Hi Sanket, Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. It worked.

Comment: @amy I think you should create a seperate question for it

Comment: i have posted a new question. If you have any solution, please help me out. Thank you.